How should I include Linux-specific libraries (libgpio) in CMake in Visual Studio?
I have a project that requires the use of libgpio. When I include the library in Cmake and in my cpp file, I get errors with anything to do with it. When I build the file, it keeps the errors, but still successfully builds. I can then run/debug the output executable as if the errors were not there.
I have this embedded in a more complicated project, originally set up in Visual Studio Code (ssh into linux VM), where this problem does not occur. Visual Studio does not work the same way, it works on local code and then copies the code into the VM when it builds. This makes me think it could be something to do with the the code living on the windows machine until the point that it is built.
My stripped down version that replicates the issue is as follows:
GPIOIssue/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(gpio_issue CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)


add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/GPIOIssue.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(gpio_issue gpiodcxx)

GPIOIssue/GPIOIssue.cpp
#include <gpiod.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const gpiod::line_request outputLineRequest{ "consumerName", gpiod::line_request::DIRECTION_OUTPUT, 0 };

    gpiod::chip chip;


    cout << "Program runs" << endl;
    return 0;
}

The error list from building the above files:
Error List snippet
Error (active)  E0059   function call is not allowed in a constant expression   gpio_issue - Linux-GCC-Debug    C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Linux\HeaderCache\1.0-588249071\usr\include\x86_64-linux-gnu\c++\9\bits\c++config.h    676
Error (active)  E0065   expected a ';'  gpio_issue - Linux-GCC-Debug    C:\Users\MyUser\source\repos\GPIOIssue\GPIOIssue.cpp    10
Error (active)  E0257   const variable "gpiod" requires an initializer  gpio_issue - Linux-GCC-Debug    C:\Users\MyUser\source\repos\GPIOIssue\GPIOIssue.cpp    8
Error (active)  E0260   explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)    gpio_issue - Linux-GCC-Debug    C:\Users\MyUser\source\repos\GPIOIssue\GPIOIssue.cpp    8
Error (active)  E0276   name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name gpio_issue - Linux-GCC-Debug    C:\Users\MyUser\source\repos\GPIOIssue\GPIOIssue.cpp    10
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "gpiod.hpp" gpio_issue - Linux-GCC-Debug    C:\Users\MyUser\source\repos\GPIOIssue\GPIOIssue.cpp    1
Message lnt-uninitialized-local Local variable is not initialized.  gpio_issue  C:\Users\MyUser\source\repos\GPIOIssue\GPIOIssue.cpp    8
To clarify, the build still succeeds, and "Program runs" is printed, but Visual Studio has lots of errors for using objects from <gpiod.hpp> which makes it difficult to develop for.

Please don't include text as images, copy'n'paste the text instead. Also, while you're at it, remove the "linux" tag, see the description for further info on that. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

maybe make a fake gpiod.hpp for windows? I don't think visual studio is really the right tool to use if your code doesn't build on windows too

The first thing you need to do is to find out why the compiler cannot find that header file. So, assuming you have installed all the GPIO components you need to check the installation to see where that file is, and add its location to the build system.

Error messages added as text. @UlrichEckhardt I think the linux tag is appropriate as I am using a linux only library, part of the linux kernal and it is the usage of the library that is causing the issue in the specific context I have described. Does that not count as linux specific?

I'm not adamant on the "linux" tag, however, your context is rather that there is code that kind-of depends on Linux-only stuff which isn't available on your non-Linux system. But, I'm not even sure if that's the issue. In any case, can you provide the command line used for compiling? In particular, question is which C++ standard version you're compiling for. I have a feeling that there's the mismatch. Lastly, try compiling a test only on/in Linux using the native compilers, just to reduce the possible influences.

I think I have been unclear in my question. The code depends on linux-only stuff, which isn't available on my windows machine. I am using Visual Studio's Linux project for remote machines feature : VSLinux.  I am able to build this code on my linux machines with GCC, but I greatly prefer Visual Studio and it seems to offer the ability to develop for Linux. However I am new to using it for developing for linux, and feel I must be missing something regarding the linux-only libaries.

Regarding tagging, I believe you need to add the wsl-2 tag, as this is what MSVS actually uses as a toolchain framework to compile in Linux over Windows, rather than remote-development. As for your issue, I am curious with the successful builds: can you confirm that by the date-time of the files? Remember that if there are compile errors, it might keep the previously successful build. Have you tried renaming or deleting them to see if they are correctly rebuilt with the current sources?
